# Replace an entire html tag with another one using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have:

```
<input id="ONE" type="..." ...>
```

I want to replace this with:

```
<select id="TWO">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
<select>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
$("#ONE").replaceAll("#TWO")
```

like described [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/replaceAll#selector). You can use replaceWith(content) if you want to specify replacing content in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using [replaceWith()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/replaceWith#content)